# $f'=0$ on a co-countable set implies $f$ constant?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose $S\subset[0,1]$ is countable, $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ is continuous, and $f'(t)=0$ for every $t\in[0,1]\setminus S$. Does it follow that $f$ is constant?

Yesterday I realized the answer's yes if $S$ is closed and $f$ has bounded variation (say $f(x)-f(0)=\mu([0,x])$. Then $\mu$ must be concentrated on $S$, and since $S$ is countable and $\mu$  vanishes on singletons it follows that $\mu=0$.)

[Today](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3311385/how-far-can-we-push-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-for-riemann-integral/3313190#3313190) I can show the answer's yes if $S$ is closed.

But.

(The answer must be yes: If there were a counterexample it would be in books next to or in place of that Lebesgue-Cantor function. But I fear some may feel this argument is somewhat lacking in "rigor"...)

**Edit:** Thanks to @MartinR for pointing out that this follows from the result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292038/if-f-is-continuous-and-fx-ge-0-outside-of-a-countable-set-then-f-is-i).
The answer there is a little intricate; one can get the idea  from the first few lines, and then give the following proof, which seems simpler to me (possibly just because stuff I figure out always seems simpler than stuff I try to read, maybe not):

Let $S=(\alpha_n)$. Let $\epsilon>0$.

If $x=\alpha_n$ there is an open interval $I_x$ with $x\in I_x$ and $$|f(s)-f(t)|<\epsilon2^{-n}\quad(s,t\in I_x).$$Otoh if $x\in[0,1]\setminus S$ there is an open interval  $I_x$ with $x\in I_x$ and $$|f(s)-f(x)|\le\epsilon|s-x|\quad(s\in I_x).$$

Now $[0,1]$ is covered by finitely many intervals $J_1,\dots,J_n$ with $J_j=I_{x_j}$. We can assume that no $J_j$ is contained in the union of the $J_k$ for $k\ne j$, and then we can assume that the $J_j$ are ordered from left to right; in particular $0\in J_1$ and $1\in J_n$.

Now $J_j\cap J_{j+1}\ne\emptyset$, since $[0,1]$ is connected. Say $y_j\in J_j\cap J_{j+1}$. Then $$|f(1)-f(0)|\le|f(0)-f(x_1)|+|f(x_1)-f(y_1)|+|f(y_1)-f(x_2)|+|f(x_2)-f(y_2)|
\\+|f(y_2)-f(x_3)|+\dots+|f(y_{n-1})-f(x_n)|+|f(x_n)-f(1)|.$$Now for each term here we may apply one or the other of the two inequalities above (depending on whether $x_j\in S$); throwing in a lot of extra stuff on the RHS to simplify the notation we obtain $$|f(1)-f(0)|\le2\epsilon\sum_k2^{-k}+\epsilon\sum|x_j-y_j|+\epsilon\sum|y_j-x_{j+1}|\le 3\epsilon.$$

So $f(1)=f(0)$, which come to think of it is not what we wanted to prove, but the same argument shows $f(b)=f(a)$ for every $[a,b]\subset[0,1]$.

Comment: Looks like a consequence of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292038/if-f-is-continuous-and-fx-ge-0-outside-of-a-countable-set-then-f-is-i to me.

Comment: @MartinR Sure enough (of course assuming the answer there is correct, which may take me a minute to  verify...)

Comment: @MartinR Sure enough; thanks.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I suppose it does count as a dup. But I've given a version of he argument in that other answer that seems to me significantly simpler...

Comment: @MartinR Hmm. Imo this is worth keeping because it's significantly simpler. So I should just post an answer in that other thread? No, that's nnot right because what I prove here does not answer that other question; what I prove here is strictly weaker.

Comment: It seems to me that your technique of choosing a non-overlapping finite cover can be applied to the more general problem ($f' \ge 0 $ on $[0, 1]\setminus S$) as well, instead of using the “Cousin's lemma” as in the other Q&A. What I mean is that the problem is essentially the same as in the other question, but that your solution is a bit simpler. If I  am right then an answer to the other thread would be nice.