# $f$ continuous with derivative $f'(x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus A$ where $A$ is countable implies $f$ constant

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I would like to find a "simple" proof of the following statement:

> Let $f\in C(\mathbb{R})$. Let $A$ be a closed and countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f'(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus A$. Show $f(x)$ must be constant.

Here, a simple proof to me can assume knowledge of Folland's Real Analysis Chapters 1-7. There are other questions on [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292038/if-f-is-continuous-and-fx-ge-0-outside-of-a-countable-set-then-f-is-i) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3313210/f-0-on-a-co-countable-set-implies-f-constant?noredirect=1&lq=1) asking for the same thing. This is a qualifying exam question and genuinely, I am stuck. Some thought suggests that $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ might be dense and so I could try to argue that $f'(x)=0$ for $x\in A$ from there. I couldn't get this to work.

The Cantor-Lebesgue function shows that if $A$ being countable is replaced by $m(A)=0$, then the result is false. So, any proof must rely on $A$ being countable.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3311385/how-far-can-we-push-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-for-riemann-integral?noredirect=1&lq=1 (not saying this gives a "simple proof")

Comment: What exactly is missing in Folland's Real Analysis' Chapters 1-7 that linked proofs use?

Comment: @Conifold One of the linked proofs used Cousin's lemma which isn't something in Folland. I was hoping there's a proof that uses material in Folland which makes it quicker/simpler. Unless of course, the proof in that second link is the best one can hope for.

Comment: On Folland I find the following sentence: It is a highly nontrivial theorem
that if F is continuous on [a, b], $F'(x)$ exists for every $x \in [a,b]\ A$ where A is
countable, and $F'\in L^1[a,b]$, then F is absolutely continuous and hence can be recovered by integration

Comment: I guess since Folland stated it highly nontrivial, there wouldn't be an easy proof(The proof in Rudin where $A=\varnothing$ uses some decomposition of functions or spaces

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isn't it immediate from a cardinality argument?

Suppose $f$ is not constant.  So there exists $a<b$ such that $\{a,b\}\subseteq f(\mathbb{R})$.

By IVT, $f(\mathbb{R})\supseteq[a,b]$.

Since $A$ is closed, the complement $\mathbb{R}-A$ is countably many open intervals.  On each of these open intervals we have $f'=0$ so $f$ is constant by MVT.  So $f(\mathbb{R}-A)$ is countable.

That leaves uncountably many values in $[a,b]$ that need to come from the countable set $A$, contradiction.

Comment: Now I understand why those other proofs are so convoluted. They do not assume that $A$ is closed, only that it is countable.

Comment: This is a very nice proof. I'm impressed that it did not rely on any measure theory or even knowledge of analysis at the level of Folland. Thank you!